# How to attach sent email with account

Tags: email, mail-server

I am working on a project where we send emails to user. Now what i want is instead of user logging-in back into our system to reply, if he replies back to that email(whichever email account he got email to). It should automatically be attached back in our system.

Can somebody share their views on how to go on about this? or any suggestions on whats a best way to do this.

Many Thanks

Comment: Are you using a particular programming language? Cause you haven't mentioned any that I see.

Answer (score 4):

You can do this using the auto-reply function in HmailServer.

Simply go to the administration windows, select an account, select the auto-reply function and set the subject and the body.

If you want to do this programatically, you can use the COM API, it can be used using various programming languages.